# With the.htaccess file, how to be redirected to a PHP script if there is not the desired parameter in the URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to filter the script in PHP. The goal is that all requests that come to my server must be redirected to my script "index.php". But this redirection should only be done if the request does not contain the parameter '?VWM6W4CP'.

I tried to put this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^VWM6W4CP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php? [L]
```

With this code if I type for example: http://localhost/project/signin.php?VWM6W4CP
it displays the signin.php page.
If I put http://localhost/project/signin.php (without the "?VWM6W4CP") I have a 404 error.

**I would like instead the 404 error that the index.php page I specified in the.htaccess file displays.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^VWM6W4CP [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

So if it is file then request not go to script index.php